# How can I avoid fall damage while Sticky-jumping?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-demoman

I have seen many tutorials on how to sticky jump effectively. I have been able to go great distances with the sticky jumper, however I an unable to stop fall damage. There aren't any thorough YouTube tutorials on it, but I have seen people do it with ease.

What I am trying to do is sticky jump, then while in air, shoot another sticky, and detonate it at the right time to avoid fall damage. I have never been able to pull it off though, is there a particular trick to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It IS possible to do, however extremely difficult. For a sticky bomb to arm, it takes 0.7 seconds. So you need to be in the air long enough for that to arm. There are no easy guides that I or my co-host are aware of. It is possible however since said co-host has done it before.

Your best bet is to learn how to chain jump with stickies, ie bouncing from sticky to sticky without touching the ground. You can do this by either strategically placing stickies on the ground, or doing this midair. While no tutorials exist for this that I am aware of, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeGIxIdvVy0) shows it in action and can give you the idea.

Oh and don't forget to air strafe, that is an invaluable tool. If you don't know how, [here is a good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdbtptfkNcc&list=PL29fhMpbR3wV-vgancWgK30MYKbTQRI_E&index=6).

Answer (score 2):

The easier alternative (not one I would suggest for effective combat) is to simply use the B.A.S.E. jumper